# ¿ Control select con AutoPostBack = true y OnSelectedIndexChanged?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo unos controles html que mediante runat="server" los uso en el lado del servidor. El problema es que con el elemento "Select" al seleccionar un elemento me debe ejecutar codigo en servidor para cargar datos en otros "Select" pero no me acepta el AutopostBack="true" ni OnSelectedIndexChanged

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSeletedIndexChanged="mySelect_SelectIndexChanged"></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de usar 'OnSele**c**tedIndexChanged' (tienes una typo ahí) puedes intentar usar el evento de cliente 'onchange':

```
<select id="mySelect" ... onchange="selectChanged()">
```

y en tu JavaScript:

```
function selectChanged() {
     var myValue= document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
     __doPostBack('mySelect', myValue);
 }
```

Tras esto, se llamará al postback de la página, que podrás usar para recoger la información enviada (myValue) en el code behind mediante la propiedad Request.Params.

Comment: Necesito que cuando haga el postback no refresque toda la pantalla sino solo la zona del select

Comment: Para eso podrías usar un UpdatePanel. Si eso no te sirve, deberías replicar lo que hace el UpdatePanel mediante llamadas ajax que actualicen la parte del dom que necesitas

Comment: Ok funciona perfecto !  Le he puesto un UpdatePane.

Comment: Tengo un problema al hacer el submit con el elemento "button" de html.Si uso onserverclick se me refresca la pagina borrando el indicador de faltavalidacion de html5. Debo usar el action del form pero como se cuando esta todo validado para cambiar dinamicamente la pagina del action donde tiene que ir?

Comment: el onclientclick / onclick no genera postback, investiga por ahí. De todas formas, es recomendable crear una nueva pregunta para que te podamos ayudar de manera más eficaz

Comment: ok gracias abrire otra pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza asp:DropDownList que al igual que el Select sirve para seleccionar un único elemento de una lista.

```
<asp:DropDownList id="AutosList" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="AutosList_SelectIndexChanged"
                    runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem Value="1">Ford</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="2">Toyota</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="3">Ferrari</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Uso el Select porque necesito escribir para visual2008 código html5 con sus validaciones. El DropDownList no me sirve.